# Trying to get property of non-object error while trying to use eloquent relationship

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, eloquent

The error is like below:

```
Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\app\views\singlePost.blade.php)
```

There is 2 tables: Comments and Users. In comments table there is a column named user_id and that refers to id column that is in users table. And there is username column in the users table.  This is how I try to print username.

```
@foreach($theComments as $theComment)
<div>{{$theComment->users->username}}</div>
<div style="border:1px solid black;margin:8px 0px 8px 0px">{{$theComment['content']}}</div>
@endforeach
```

and controller:

```
 public function singlePost(Posts $post)
    {
        $id = $post['id'];
        $comments = Comments::where('post_id','=',$id)->get();
        $users = Users::all();
        return View::make('singlePost')->with('thePost', $post)->with('theComments', $comments)->with('theUser', $users);
    }
```

and /Model/Comments.php

```
<?php
class Comments extends Eloquent{
    protected $fillable = array('user_id');
    public function users(){
        return $this->belongsTo('Users');
    }
}
```

What's the problem and how can i solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I suggest you rename the relationship to just `user()` (At the beginning thought it would return a collection). The source of the error is probably a comment that has no user assigned.

The best way would just be to exclude those from your query. You can use `has()` for that

```
$comments = Comments::has('user')->where('post_id','=',$id)->get();
```

And you should also *eager load* the user relationship, otherwise you have a n+1 queries issue:

```
$comments = Comments::has('user')->with('user')->where('post_id','=',$id)->get();
```

### Edit

Try wrapping this if around it in your view:

```
@foreach($theComments as $theComment)
    @if($user = $theComment->users)
        <div>{{$user->username}}</div>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Comment: every single comment has user_id. Why should i change it to user?

Comment: Changing it to user is just a recommendation because it makes semantically more sense. I'll update my question with a piece of code you can try in a sec.

Comment: as I've learnt now that must be user() not users() as you said. because laravel looks for 's'. thanks.

Comment: Wait so you just had to rename it to `user()` and it all worked?

Answer (score -1):

You need to load the relationship first

```
$comments = Comments::with('users')->where('post_id','=',$id)->get();
```

See http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#eager-loading

Comment: where? I don't see anything like that in tutorial that i watch.

Comment: May I know what's wrong with the answer? Just down voting and moving away doesn't really help.

Comment: Eager loading `users` won't help with the problem. You can access relations without loading them before (lazy loading) (Although it's definitely not recommended in this case)

Comment: Yes, but that will cause extra Db queries to fire.

Comment: Sure but it won't cause this error => not the right answer